# Highcharts-values' padding do not display correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, highcharts

[image: Highcharts Padding Error]

Hello everyone!
I got this problem that you see on the image that I uploaded.
I get this only on Firefox & IE (Version>=8, works fine on 7).
Chrome displays the chart correctly.
Here is how the blocks are described:
      series: {

```
            stacking: 'percent',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
        }
 series: [{
        name: 'Mit Fotos',
        id: 'mfGW',
        pointWidth: 30,
        color: '#7cb5ec',
        linkedTo: 'GW',
        data: [42],
        stack: 'one'
    }, {
        name: 'Ohne Fotos',
        linkedTo: 'GW',
        pointWidth: 30,
        color: '#434348',
        id: 'ofGW',
            data: [19],
        stack: 'one'
    },
    {
            name: 'GW',
            id: 'GW',
            pointWidth: 90,
            color: '#8d4653',
        data: [61]

    }
```

Chart type is bar.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle demo that shows exactly this problem, and post a link to this demo here?

Comment: and can you describe what the actual problem is...?

Comment: The numbers are misplaced.